# How to enter text in input box using Samsung smart tv emulator

Tags: javascript, html, css, samsung-smart-tv, television

i made a simple Samsung smart TV application, which let the user to input his name  before interning to the main page, it works correctly,, but the problem is how the user can inter his name while the remote control which shown in the emulator doesn't have letters buttons!!! also their is no cursor to active the text box!!
AS i see in Samsung advertisement the user uses his Samsung phone to enter text !!!
so,, how can i use remote control to enter text?? and what about cursor?? 
please ...anybody can help!!

her is the html code:

```
  <label>Enter your name: <input type="text" class="test">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" /><input type="submit" value="Welcome" class="button" /> </label>
```

and this is the css code:

```
 label {display:block; margin:20px; width:420px; overflow:auto; font-family:sans-serif; font-size:25px; color: black; text-shadow:0 0 2px #ddd; padding:20px 10px 10px 0;}

.test {float:right; width:200px; padding:5px; border: 2px solid red; border-radius:7px; font-size:20px; -webkit-transition: box-shadow linear 1s; transition: box-shadow linear 1s; margin-top:-1px;}

.test:focus {box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;}

.button {

border: none;
background-color: #ff00;
padding: 4px 16px;
margin-left :100px;
margin-top: 10px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest emulator, switch the remote view to the old remote, the one with letter keys associated with numbers.